# Loading images in javascript the interactive way without breaking compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, asynchronous

On my website, I share a lot of large images. I use the following HTML tags to display the images:

```
<img src="/path/to/image" width=x height=y alt="whatever">
```

Of course the values are replaced with proper values.

I would like to implement a solution so that all browsers (including those capable of supporting ONLY basic HTML and images including the Arachne browser) can access the image, while the browsers with javascript can see the image loading in action. (for example, the loading screen followed by the image appearing instantly)

The following URL gave me an idea:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript

It suggested I should use this type of javascript

```
var image = document.images[0];
var downloadingImage = new Image();
downloadingImage.onload = function(){
    image.src = this.src;   
};
downloadingImage.src = "http://an.image/to/aynchrounously/download.jpg";
```

and this type of CSS:

```
img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  background: url(loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The problem with this setup is that browsers that don't support javascript or CSS will always see the loading graphic and therefore become frustrated.

Is there a way I can achieve this loading effect but still allow browsers without javascript or CSS to still see the proper image?

The only thing I can think of is to use javascript to somehow force-stop an image from loading but I don't know if such commands exist. In code, I'm thinking:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('delayme').dontLoadImage=true;
//stop image from loading
//ajax code to fetch image url as if it was html
document.getElementById('delayme').dontLoadImage=false;
//let image continue loading
</script>
<img ID="delayme" src="image.jpg" width=100 height=100 alt="image">
```

Any ideas?

and remember, the image must appear regardless of whether the user has javascript enabled or not.

**UPDATE**

So far, this code works for my needs, but only if both javascript and CSS are enabled or if both javascript and css are disabled. However if CSS is enabled and javascript is disabled, then the image stays hidden. How do I fix this?

```
<style>
    img{display:none}
</style>

<div ID="loading">
</div> 

<script>
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML="Loading picture...";
</script>

<img src="http://127.0.0.1/x.jpg" onload="func()">
<script>
    function func(){
       document.images[0].style.display="block";
       document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML="Picture loaded";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you encountering browsers that do not support CSS on a regular basis?

Comment: @hopkins-matt most browsers allows configure non-javascript and/or non-css options. There are console browsers that doesn't renders any css or js at all

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes, I completely understand the lack of JS. I just don't find a large number of no CSS visitors to any of my sites.

Comment: I think that users that have this options configured are less of 0.00001% of the web users, but many people want to allow this little percent of users to browse perfectly through the pages `:)`

Comment: @Mike is there any issue with placing each image inside a `<div>`? or would you prefer to avoid that?

Comment: I can place images inside DIVS. No issue there

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this:

```
 var asyncImgs = []; // empty array to store the img src's to load them asyncronously
 var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
 for(i = 0; i < imgs.length ; i++) {
      asyncImgs.push(imgs[i].src); // store the src
      imgs[i].src = null; // remove the src
 }
```

With this method, the non-javascript browsers render the normal `<img>` tag, but with javascript you iterate all images in page, stores the `src` into an empty array, and then remove the `src` of the image. You can add your code to load images with `new Image()` now.

Good luck!

Comment: But wouldn't the request for the image have already fired when the browser received the `img` element with the source set before the JS nulls it?

Comment: Yes, browser receives it, it's because it works with javascript disabled. But if you put this code just **after** all img tags are defined, you don't see the trick.

Comment: But what is the point of nulling the `src` on the `img` tags and then reloading the images asynchronously if they have already been requested by the browser?

Comment: If a user has JS enabled wouldn't they possibly end up loading the images twice?

Comment: Are you reading the OP post? He is asking for that. He has several `<img>` tags, and he wants to load it asyncronously (maybe for design requirements) but preserve img tags in non-javascript browsers. You are telling us that the load of a `<img>` tag is sufficient, I know, but OP doesn't wants that

Comment: Yes, I just feel like your answer may be misguided since it will end up with the OP's site requesting the same image twice if JS is enabled. If he wants a loading effect for those with JS and CSS enabled, why not just hide the image and maybe overlay or insert a loading GIF until it is fully loaded instead of nulling it and then requesting the image again?

Comment: I think the same, but this decision is in the side of the OP. Only if he is pronounced here and explain us what and why. But this is a correct answer for the question of the post.

Comment: But wait, doesn't that execute too late tho? because what if data up to `<img>` is downloaded then theres some network delay caused by the client ISP? wouldn't the image try to load before the javascript begins processing?

Comment: Images will be loading after DOM is ready. So if you put this code after the images (as I said in other comment) the browser don't loads the image at all. If you put this content in a `onload` event, you'll obtain the opposite (first load images, second nulled it).

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that even if you put this directly after the last `img` element that some browsers would have already started requesting the images before the JS fires.

Comment: First is DOM parsing, then loads external resources. However, let @Mike to explain what he needs and why he needs this kind of behaviour. We are discussing here for a topic that nobody of us can understand

Comment: I just did an experiment using 12 images from `placehold.it` in JSFiddle on Firefox and 5 began loading before being nulled using your script immediately after the last image element. Mind you nothing else was on this page. If the OP were to introduce other scripts before your script this may be even more exaggerated.

Comment: Yes, but there aren't no more alternatives to achieve what he needs. He needs `<img>` tags displayed normally with a browser with javascript disallowed. If you know another kind of code be free to let a response here. I go home now, I've been working for more 11 hours today in the office. See you tomorrow!

Comment: However, if you make a fiddle you can share with us, or not? And remember that jsfiddle loads the javascript with onload or ondomready, but you need to choose them

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jun6y2a0/ JSFiddle only loads it `onload` or `ondomreday` if you place it in the JS section and set it to those options. I placed it within a script tag immediately after the last `img` element. I mentioned an alternative above, but have not had time to make an answer yet.

Comment: I put http in the images of your fiddle, but I don't achieve to see any loaded images. Maybe I have a supercomputer ?

Comment: But with your alternative you need to hide via css. If a user visit the page with your alternative without javascript, we doesn't see the images because them are hide (assuming css enabled but javascript disabled). However, post your answer when you have time, maybe if I see the code makes more sense than my answer. But my intention in this answer only was to help OP. I quit right now from work. Good evening!

Answer (score 0):

This will work with CSS on and JS off or both on. I don't know if I've seen anyone running JS with CSS off, but if that is something you are trying to solve, I'll have to rethink this quite a bit. I'll be honest, it's not really pretty, but it works.

If only CSS is enabled or if both JS and CSS are disabled, the page loads like any other basic HTML page. The images are loaded from the `src`.

Once we have JS support, we insert a loading `<div>` before the image and hide the image until it is loaded at which time we show it and remove the loading div. This is the best case I could think of without having to enclose every image tag in a `<div>` in the HTML.

**HTML/JS:**

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/05S_Jan_7_2012_1035Z.jpg" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/998x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/997x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/996x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/995x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/994x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/993x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/992x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/991x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/990x999.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/999x991.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/999x992.png"/>
<img src="https://placehold.it/999x993.png">
<img src="https://placehold.it/999x994.png"/>
<script>
  var imgList = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    imgList[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div id="loading' + i + '" style="height:' + imgList[i].clientHeight + 'px;width:' + imgList[i].clientWidth + 'px;background: url(\'http://loading.io/assets/img/default-loader.gif\') center no-repeat;z-index:9999;"></div>');
    imgList[i].style.display = "none";
    imgList[i].onload = function() {
      this.style.display = "block";
      this.previousSibling.remove();
    };
  }
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/abychvxc/

Answer (score 0):

After looking at answers and my own testing, it turns out that I needed the noscript tag and that I needed to fully generate a new image to attach to the existing DOM structure. Because of Internet Explorer's bugs, I forced internet explorer to load the image an old-fashioned-ish way where the status isn't updated as the image loads. In other browsers, the load is more progressive because those browsers were invented correctly (I hope). Nevertheless, this code works for me and I will use it as my starting point.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="LOAD"></div>
<div ID="IMAGE">
<noscript>
<img src="/x.jpg">
</noscript>
</div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById('LOAD');
x.innerHTML='Loading...';
downloadingImage=document.createElement('IMG');
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") == -1){
  downloadingImage.onload=function(){
      x.innerHTML='';
      document.getElementById('IMAGE').appendChild(downloadingImage);
  }
}else{
  x.innerHTML='IE';
  document.getElementById('IMAGE').appendChild(downloadingImage);
}
downloadingImage.src = "/x.jpg";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's pretty good solution too! I almost suggested the `noscript` tag, but assumed you didn't want to modify the html syntax.